# I am planning to petition citizenship for my brother in the US but have no birth certificate...?

Tags: united-states, immigration, citizenship, birth-certificate

One of the requirements on the [USCS.gov](https://www.uscis.gov/family/family-us-citizens/bringing-siblings-live-united-states-permanent-residents) was to fill out the I-30 for petitioning of siblings. The instructions said to obtain a birth certificate but neither him nor me have birth certificates(I just became naturalized).

What can I do in this case? Get DNA testing...? Not sure how this works.

Comment: Where was he born and why doesn't he have a birth certificate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about immigration, not the law or legal process. See [Expatriates Stack Exchange](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usa+immigration) for a more appropriate question venue.

Comment: @phoog, he was born in a war-torn country. No documentation, birth records from his country..

Comment: @Nij, Really? This question refers to the LEGAL process for petitioning the US government in regards to immigration. How does this not fall into the topics of this site..?

Comment: Do you want the question answered or are you just aiming to have it technically on-topic somewhere?

Comment: It's not legal process either, it's an administrative process. That it happens to be a process based on a regulation based on a law doesn't make it about **the** legal process. If you're going to argue technicality, at least be right and understand the words used, too.

Comment: Law - the system of rules that a particular country or community recognizes as regulating the actions of its members and may enforce by the imposition of penalties.

Comment: Okay, sure, this question is technically on-topic by virtue of stubbornness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details are specified in [8 CFR 204.1(f)](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=e060d4b7266ce1ca301da5873425ab61&mc=true&node=sp8.1.204.a&rgn=div6#se8.1.204_11). In this case you would need evidence that X is a sibling, and "must be in the form of primary evidence, if available". But, "When it is established that primary evidence is not available, secondary evidence may be accepted". The service (US Customs and Immigration Service) "will refer to the Department of State's Foreign Affairs Manual", and may determine that the document just doesn't exist for the country; or it may be lacking in the case of an individual. Ultimately, "The determination of what evidence is credible and the weight to be given that evidence shall be within the sole discretion of the Service" (USCIS). If the document is in a foreign language, it "must be accompanied by an English translation which has been certified by a competent translator".

A non-exhaustive list of secondary evidence is given in that subsection, and includes baptismal certificate with church seal; affidavits sworn to by persons who were living at the time and who have personal knowledge of the event to which they attest (most relevant being relationship); school records which included relevant family information; census records listing name, place of birth, and date of birth or age of the petitioner. DNA evidence could be used, provided that the science is sufficiently clear and convincing.

Comment: What is "the Service" in this context?